# How to draw polygons from a bw image in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to draw polygons from a bw image.

Considering a square matrix 3x3, some of the elements are 0 and some of them are 255. What I want is to draw straight lines that separate black pixels from white pixels to form a polygon or a line through a set of points, and look for intersections with a segment line.

I have been using `polyxpoly` for simple situations, but I think it's not a good function to  find polygons in a random image.

for example, if my image looks like this,

[0 0 255;0 255 255; 255 255 255]

I want to find a line through the points wich are the vertices of the pixels given by

x = [2 2 1 1 0]
y = [0 1 1 2 2]

where x is rows and y is columns.

any ideas?

Comment: you try to find lines using the Hough Transform, take a look at http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/houghlines.html